# Como aplicar str_pad correctamente a una cadena que tiene asentos

Tags: php, php5

Tengo esta situación, estoy aplicando la función

> str_pad

para rellenar una cadena de texto con espacios, pero el problema radica cuando la cadena contiene acentos (tildes o ñ), dado que me cuenta ese carácter como si fueran dos, lo que causa que se rellene la cadena con un carácter menos. Ejemplo

```
$texto="niña";
echo str_pad($texto,7,"-");
```

**Salida obtenida:**

> "niña--"

**Salida deseada:**

> "niña---"

No se si haya una forma fácil de corregir esto, o ya hay que hacerlo manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré en la [documentación de php](http://php.net/manual/es/function.str-pad.php), esta solución es un poco larga pero funciona perfectamente.

```
function str_pad_unicode($str, $pad_len, $pad_str = ' ', $dir = STR_PAD_RIGHT) {
    $str_len = mb_strlen($str);
    $pad_str_len = mb_strlen($pad_str);
    if (!$str_len && ($dir == STR_PAD_RIGHT || $dir == STR_PAD_LEFT)) {
        $str_len = 1; // @debug
    }
    if (!$pad_len || !$pad_str_len || $pad_len <= $str_len) {
        return $str;
    }

    $result = null;
    $repeat = ceil($str_len - $pad_str_len + $pad_len);
    if ($dir == STR_PAD_RIGHT) {
        $result = $str . str_repeat($pad_str, $repeat);
        $result = mb_substr($result, 0, $pad_len);
    } else if ($dir == STR_PAD_LEFT) {
        $result = str_repeat($pad_str, $repeat) . $str;
        $result = mb_substr($result, -$pad_len);
    } else if ($dir == STR_PAD_BOTH) {
        $length = ($pad_len - $str_len) / 2;
        $repeat = ceil($length / $pad_str_len);
        $result = mb_substr(str_repeat($pad_str, $repeat), 0, floor($length))
                    . $str
                       . mb_substr(str_repeat($pad_str, $repeat), 0, ceil($length));
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Es un bug de PHP, los developers hicieron su función para que funcionara lo que propones, te dejo la liga y un ejemplo. [Bug str_pad](https://gist.github.com/nebiros/226350)

```
<?php

function mb_str_pad( $texto, $longitud, $relleno = '', $tipo_pad = STR_PAD_RIGHT, $codificacion = null  ){
    $diff = empty( $codificacion ) ? ( strlen( $texto ) - mb_strlen( $texto )) : ( strlen( $texto ) - mb_strlen( $texto, $codificacion ) );
    return str_pad( $texto, ($longitud + $diff), $relleno, $tipo_pad ); 
}

$arr = array( 'laptop', 'ñu', 'niña', 'computadora', 'silicón', 'gato' );

foreach( $arr as $a ){
    echo mb_str_pad( $a, 7, '-' ) . '<br>';
}

?>
```

Comment: Aun que tuve que usar la solución que encontré en la documentación de php, esta solución me parece mas óptima y me gusta mas, voy a probarla y ver que tal funciona